# Where and how can I connect firebase in my react-native with redux-persist

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm working on a react-native app, where I want to save data online with firebase for now but probably want to switch to another backend later. Therefore I would prefer not to depend on the firebase offline and persistance options but using redux and redux-persist. But I'm struggling what would be the best way to implement and if I could connect it as easy like redux-persist?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get a very useful answer without a lot more detail about your data and user requirements, and the scope of the project. However, I do know that firebase realtime database is very unique in the way data is stored, which makes it difficult to swap out later for a different persistence layer.

I would recommend using firestore, which comes with offline support out of the box. Or building a proper associative, idempotent synchronization layer for offline support from the start (like google docs).

Unless your app is single-player -- then you're probably on the right track with dumping the state on the disk. Again, I'd need a lot more information.